# Android Fragment Error: Error Inflating Class Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have researched this problem countless times and followed numerous tutorials step by step and cannot seem to get my app to load without this error.

```
02-21 11:15:46.759 2624-2624/com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments, PID: 2624
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments/com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166)
    at com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity@ef610c0 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
    at com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.StartFragment.onAttach(StartFragment.java:83)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:932)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1228)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2201)
    at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5546)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2166) 
    at com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The following are my MainActivity jar file and xml file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Fragment fragment;
Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    StartFragment myFragment = new StartFragment();
    ft.add(R.id.myFragment, myFragment);
    ft.commit();



}
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fragment 3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:name="com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.StartFragment"
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That's how ends copy &paste without understanding...  You are throwing this exception from onAttach of the StartFragment

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.example.brandon.transitioningfragments.MainActivity@ef610c0 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

`MainActivity` needs to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`, due to something that you are doing in `onAttach()` of `StartFragment`.

Also, your code seems to be trying to use `StartFragment` both as a static fragment (via `<fragment>`) and as a dynamic fragment (via a `FragmentTransaction`). It is unlikely that this is what you really want. Pick one approach.

Comment: Yes this worked. It was a pretty stupid error on my part, thank you for helping me though!